# Why can't I get a result from an XPath with namespace in the root element?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, namespaces, nokogiri

This is probably an XML namespace newbie question but I can't figure out how to get an XPath to work with the following trunctated XML with this particular root element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CreateOrUpdateEventsRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://dhamma.org" version="3-0-0">
   <LanguageKey>
    <IsoCode>en</IsoCode>
  </LanguageKey>
  <Publish>
    <Value>true</Value>
  </Publish>
  <Events>
    <Event>
      <EventKey>
        <LocationKey>
          <SubDomain>rasmi</SubDomain>
        </LocationKey>
        <EventId>10DayPDFStdTag</EventId>
      </EventKey>
    </Event>
  </Events>
   </LanguageKey>
</CreateOrUpdateEventsRequest>
```

Using Ruby and Nokogiri (with a  just updated libxml2), it works fine with XPath only if I delete all the extra info in the root element, making it:

```
<CreateOrUpdateEventsRequest>
```

Otherwise nothing works:

```
$> @doc.xpath("//CreateOrUpdateEventsRequest") #=> [] with original header, an array of nodes with modified header
$> @doc.xpath("//LanguageKey") #=> [] with the original header, an array of nodes with modified header

$> @doc.xpath("//xmlns:LanguageKey") #=> undefined namespace prefix with the original
```

How do I address namespaces like this with XPath?

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for the help.

The answer seems to be that the XML re-declared XMLNS when it should have declared the namespace with a prefix as in `xmlns:myns`.

From www.w3.org:

> The XML specification reserves all names beginning with the letters 'x', 'm', 'l' in any combination of upper- and lower-case for use by the W3C. To date three such names have been given definitions—although these names are not in the XML namespace, they are listed here as a convenience to readers and users:

- xml: See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-XMLDecl and http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#xmlReserved
- xmlns: See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-decl
- xml-stylesheet: See The xml-stylesheet processing instruction

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Nokogiri nor Ruby,
but you need to register a prefix for namespace `http://dhamma.org`

When I read http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html
I understand you must do something like

```
$> @doc.xpath('//dha:LanguageKey', 'dha' => 'http://dhamma.org')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to consider. Starting with code to create a Nokogiri::XML::Document:

```
require 'nokogiri'

XML = <<EOT
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CreateOrUpdateEventsRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://dhamma.org" version="3-0-0">
       <LanguageKey>
        <IsoCode>en</IsoCode>
      </LanguageKey>
      <Publish>
        <Value>true</Value>
      </Publish>
      <Events>
        <Event>
          <EventKey>
            <LocationKey>
              <SubDomain>rasmi</SubDomain>
            </LocationKey>
            <EventId>10DayPDFStdTag</EventId>
          </EventKey>
        </Event>
      </Events>
       </LanguageKey>
    </CreateOrUpdateEventsRequest>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(XML)
```

Here's the root node's name:

```
doc.root.name # => "CreateOrUpdateEventsRequest"
```

[The docs](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) say:

> When using CSS, if the namespace is called “xmlns”, you can even omit the namespace name.

```
doc.at('CreateOrUpdateEventsRequest').name # => "CreateOrUpdateEventsRequest"
doc.at('LanguageKey').to_xml # => "<LanguageKey>\n        <IsoCode>en</IsoCode>\n      </LanguageKey>"
```

Using XPath, we can specify the default namespace as:

```
doc.at('//xmlns:LanguageKey').to_xml # => "<LanguageKey>\n        <IsoCode>en</IsoCode>\n      </LanguageKey>"
```

Sometimes, if there are a lot of namespaces it makes sense to use `collect_namespaces` and pass them in:

```
name_spaces = doc.collect_namespaces # => 
doc.at('//xmlns:LanguageKey', name_spaces).to_xml # => "<LanguageKey>\n        <IsoCode>en</IsoCode>\n      </LanguageKey>"
```

You'll need to look through the documentation for [Nokogiri::XML::Node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) for more information on the various methods.

I recommend using CSS selectors for simplicity and readability over XPath, as a first try. I think XPath has more functionality but it makes my eyes bug out sometimes, so I prefer CSS.